# Not able to use route.push, it errors 'Maximum call stack size exceeded'

Tags: vue.js

I have recently upgraded my application's Bootstrap from 2.0.0-rc.18 to Bootstrap 4.4.1

The problem is that I am unable to route between pages within my application. My application does the following to route at the moment

```
console.log('before')
this.$router.push({ name: 'form-customer' })
console.log('after')
```

After the Bootstrap upgrade, as soon as route.push is called, I get thousands of errors in the console - 'Maximum call stack size exceeded'

if I change the code to as below, it just works

```
 window.location.href = "./fred/66"
```

Why does the route.push not work after Bootstrap upgrade?

I have narrowed it down to router-link. My template is as below

```
<tr v-for="(list, index) in filteredList" :key="'i-' + index">
    <td class="text-center icon-cell">
        <router-link :to="`form-customer/${list.Id}?test=true`" ><i class="fa-fw fas fa-mobile-alt " v-b-tooltip.hover title="Mobile"></i></router-link>

    </td>  
</tr>
```

The above loop works fine but as soon as I add another router-link as below, I get the error even without clicking on the link

```
<tr v-for="(list, index) in filteredList" :key="'i-' + index">
    <td class="text-center icon-cell">
        <router-link :to="`form-customer/${list.Id}?test=true`" ><i class="fa-fw fas fa-mobile-alt " v-b-tooltip.hover title="Mobile"></i></router-link>
        <router-link :to="`form-customer/${list.Id}?test=true`" ><i class="fa-fw fas fa-mobile-alt " v-b-tooltip.hover title="Mobile"></i></router-link>

    </td>  
</tr>
```

Comment: Did u use `router.beforeEach`? If yes  then add your whole code in router

Comment: when you say 'add your whole code in router' what do you mean?

Comment: I mean add router code in your question. I need to investigate your code

Comment: I see. I did have beforeEach event but I removed it. So there is no beforeEach now. Also I tried putting console.log (added in question) and it came out only once

Comment: With routing such error is usually the product of infinite redirect looping, so do you use redirecting anywhere?

Comment: @user2837961 can you show your router code?

Comment: I have finally narrowed it down to router-link. Please see my template code in the question

Comment: @user2837961 use index in your loop, not the id.

Comment: Can you share your router code

Answer (score 0):

```
// router.js
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: routes,
})

export.default router

// main.js

import Vue from 'vue';
import '/imports/app.js'
import router from '. /router.js'

this.$router.push({ name: 'form-customer' })
```

might help you